# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method b(Landroid/os/Bundle;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/IBinder;)V in class Landroidx/core/app/e

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am getting this error on play console. Unable to properly figure out the source of the problem.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.madhurtexttospeechtts.madhur, PID: 7705
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method b(Landroid/os/Bundle;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/IBinder;)V in class Landroidx/core/app/e; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.app.e' appears in base.apk)
    at androidx.media.d$h.h(Unknown Source:46)
    at androidx.media.d$h$d.onGetRoot(Unknown Source:15)
    at android.service.media.MediaBrowserService$ServiceBinder$1.run(MediaBrowserService.java:229)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError` usually caused by minifying and not adding proguard configuration.
Check your proguard config make sure you `-keep` the class containing the method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this to your proguard-rules.pro file

```
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.* {*;}
```

if error not solved after that also then re install your jdk